# Android 4(.4) ADB shell change hotspot password

Tags: android, android-source

Does anyone know if there is a way to change the tethering/hotspot password using ADB on android 4(.4)?

I have only seen 1 solution and that is to use the `input` command to send key events.

That will not work for us.

Comment: 1) This would probably only be possible on a rooted device (but then you did tag this `android-source`).  2) Again because you tagged this `android source` look through that source and figure out where the password is stored.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I was hoping to avoid digging through the source but it sounds like there are not exposed commands or anything for doing this from the shell.